Motion sensor light always on?
Lutron motion sensor light in foyer is always on, and on/off button doesn't work. Wired according to instructions, or so we think!! Any ideas? Breaker is currently off.


(a) what does the white/green wire connect to? (b) one of the black wires appears to be going to a white wire - that implies a switch loop - does the other black wire go to the matching (same cable) black wire or someplace else?

Is there another switch in the circuit (two- or three-way)?

No, this is the only switch attached to this circuit. I will post another pic with the wiring inside of the box

What does the tag and/or instructions say about the green-sleeved white wire? Is this a new switch or a switch that used to work correctly here?

Sometimes they fail.
It's unclear if this is "old, may have failed" or "new, return as defective" from the question.
In either case, if it's wired correctly and does not work correctly, replacement is the logical solution.
However, it appears that this switch location is wired incorrectly and is switching the neutral, not the hot. That's a code violation (because it's unsafe) but will "work" for a dumb switch. It likely won't work for a smart switch which expects to get power from the unswitched hot to operate.
I await a response to the questions in comments, but presumably the switch also needs the white sleeved with green to be connected to the neutral (since it appears you have neutral here) or ground if you did not, and likely the green sleeve is supposed to be removed if you can connect it to neutral. That wire (which seems to be disconnected in one of your pictures and connected to ground in the other) is likely the other side of powering the switch. If the switch terminals are connected to neutral, when the light is on there will only be a volt or so between the switch terminals and the white/green wire. If switching the hot, there will be 120V between the incoming hot and that wire regardless of the light being on.
IF (and it's a big if, which you need to check with a meter) the rest of this cable is wired correctly (but you have to check, because this switch WAS NOT) the solution would be to cut the black wire in the cable, attach it to the black wires from the switch, and connect the white wires from the cables with a wire nut. Connect the white sleeved with green from the switch as the instructions indicate when you have neutral in the box. I'd guess that's going to be "remove green sleeve and connect to white" but follow the instructions, which you can read and I can't, as you have not specified a switch model.

I did look at the manual (this is an MS-OPS2) and your directions are correct - green sleeve removed when using (as preferred when available) neutral.
